# Azure logic app with Condition

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I am creating the logic app when I want to send an email when there are duplicate entries created in my database, and until those are not removed email should be triggered after some interval

As per Logic App, we can create a trigger on SQL when data is inserted or modified as bellow

[image]

So I selected the first option then I am adding another action which will run my SQL script to check the logic of duplicate entries

[image]

and last I have added another action to send an email.

Now I want my last action of sending email to be executed only when my query comes up with some result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **[Condition Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement)** to check whether the given result set is valid if the condition satisfies then you can send the email

See my logic app below.

[image]

Here I've added the `Execute a Stored Procedure` Action. My stored procedure returns resultsets, you can use the logic for checking the duplicate and in the next condition you can check the duplicate result is `true` (or) `false`. If it's true you can send email else not to.

**Update 1**

How to Add condition control

[image]

Comment: Hi @jayendran
I am trying to implement this without store procedure , and I also can see Addcondition option , I only see  AddAction and Add Parallel branch option when i click on + sign

Comment: @ravikishan Please see my **update1** in the above answer. The StoreProcedure is a recommended way to put all the logic into a single unit for validating the duplicate, instead of an Execute SQL query. See below @Johns-305 answer as well. However, if you still want to implement this without SP you can just replace my `Storeprocedure` activity with your `execute sql query` action

Comment: thanks a ton !!!! It is working cheers !!! now I am just trying to send same result set as attachment in email

Comment: @ravikishan Cheers. You can do that also easily. Give it a try by yourself. You can also Upvote my answer if you really find it helpful. Cheers again !

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off programming the duplicate condition detection into a Stored Procedure rather than a SQL Trigger then using the Logic App change Trigger.

Instead, use a Logic App and Recurrence to call the Stored Procedure that queries for duplicates and returns the necessary meta data.

Trigger + table + change will be less reliable then you expect and much harder to maintain.