# Azure LogicApp with Conditional Control is not working

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

My Service Bus queue is receiving telemetry of 2 different objects. For Object1 is have to send mail to MailId1 and for Object2 j have to send mail to MailId2. Also, I have to use some of the content from JSON telemetry as the body of my mail.

For a single object, it is working fine. In my logic app, I have used service bus (its queue is receiving telemetry messages) followed by parse JSON (to parse content as JSON) and lastly SMTP to send mail. In case I need to make decisions based on JSON, what workflow can I use in LogicApp?

I have used Condition action as shown in the image below. 
[image]
JSON parsed in IF condition is

```
{
    "properties": {
        "dbt": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "latitude": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "longitude": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "owner": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "speed": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "stdb": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "timeCreated": {
            "type": "integer"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

JSON parsed in ELSE condition

```
{
    "properties": {
        "message": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "owner": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "timeCreated": {
            "type": "integer"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

For either of the telemetry, the condition always fails and executes else part. IF part is never executed. Where am I going wrong in setting condition for IF part?

Any help would be appropriated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure logic app with Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930837/azure-logic-app-with-condition)

Comment: @Jayendran, please re-read the question, I have added some more details

Comment: Can you check the received body ? You may have some encoding problem.

Comment: @Thomas, I have uploaded simulator code and body at https://github.com/Dharita/TrackingSimulator

Comment: So the contentData is base64 encoded, try to decode it, the is a function or it. Also check post related to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement).